# How to give proof of union of subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A $\subset$ S, B $\subset$ S prove the following:

A $\subset$ B if and only if A $\cup$ B = B

I don't know how to prove this.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this as an example on how to do these kind of problems.

Suppose $A \cup B = B$. Let $x \in A$. Then $x \in A \cup B$ as $x$ is in at least one of the sets. Hence $x \in B$, so $A \subset B$.

Suppose $A \subset B$. Then $x \in A \implies x \in B$, hence $x \in A \cup B \implies x \in A $ or $ x \in B \implies x \in B$ or $x \in B \implies x \in B$, so $A \cup B \subset B$. On the other hand, of course $B \subset A \cup B$, so it is clear that $B = A \cup B$. Hence we are done.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding.

I followed you up until the fifth line before "hence". I do not understand some of these symbols ⟹ and Aorx

Comment: Aorx was a typing mistake. I have corrected it. $\implies$ is the "implies" conditional. Whatever is **after** the $\implies$ **is a consequence of, or follows from** whatever is **before** the $\implies$. I hope you understand now.

Comment: I get it! thank you so much for the structure of the proof, very helpful

Comment: You are welcome. Besides, using mathematical symbols like $\forall$, $\exists$, $\implies$ etc. will be very helpful to you in your journey of mathematics.